# Triangle inequality for singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

For a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times p}$, let $\sigma_1(A) \geq \sigma_{2}(A), \cdots, \sigma_{p}(A) \geq 0$ denote the singular values of $A$.

Since the operator norm of is just the largest singular value (i.e. $\sigma_1(A) = \| A \|_2$), we have that for matrices $A,B$, $\sigma_1(A+B) \leq \sigma_1(A) + \sigma_1(B)$.

Is this triangle inequality true for any other singular values as well? I think I found a counter example for the second largest.

Is there something interesting to say about it besides just "no"?

Comment: We have [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl's_inequality_in_matrix_theory) for singular values, which tells us that
$$
\sigma_j(A) + \sigma_k(B) \leq \sigma_i(A + B) \leq \sigma_r(A) + \sigma_s(B), \quad j + k - n \geq i \geq r + s - 1.
$$
More specificially, we have
$$
\sigma_i(A) + \sigma_n(B) \leq \sigma_i(A + B) \leq \sigma_i(A) + \sigma_1(B), \quad 1 \leq i \leq n.
$$

Comment: Usually for operators, the $2$-norm denotes the Hilvert-Schmidt norm. I would denote the operator norm by $\|A\|_\infty$ or just $\|A\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we always have $\sigma_k(A+B)\leq \sigma_k(A) + \sigma_1(B)$ for any $k=1,\dots, p$. In fact taking $k=1$ recovers the inequality that you have.